# Are Crownfield cereal boxes with plant-based ingredients vegan?

Tags: is-it-vegan

As an example, *Crownfield -Special- Flakes Red Fruit* is a cereal sold by Lidl. The ingredients listed appear to be vegan and the box has a "vegetarian" label. Here's the simplified list:

> Wholegrain wheat, ground rice, sugar, freeze dried fruit
> (strawberries, cherries, raspberries), brown invert sugar syrup,
> barley malt extract, salt, glucose syrup.

At first I thought this might be because it indicates that it "may contain milk", i.e. there's risk of potential cross-contamination in the factory. But then I found another Crownfield cereal box, *Fruit & Fibre*, which also has the "main contain milk" warning yet it has a vegan label. Which left me wondering: why do they consider one to be vegan and the other not? Or is it merely an oversight?

To be clear, this question is not about the "may contain milk" issue, which is unfortunately too common. But rather, I wish to know if the cereal contains animal derived ingredients or a manufacturing process that would make it definitely not plant-based.

On a related note, Aldi sells *Harvest Morn Crisp Cereal Strawberry* which is in the same situation, seemingly vegan ingredients, but labeled vegetarian and "may contain milk". But at least I was able to see it considered vegan by [veganwomble](https://veganwomble.com/our-unofficial-aldi-vegan-list/). On the other hand, the Crownfield cereal in question has "vegan status unknown" on [Open Food Facts](https://world.openfoodfacts.org/product/20621452/crownfield-special-flakes-red-berries).

I have not yet attempted to contact Lidl, but if someone else has already, or has reason to believe that Crownfield Flakes Red Fruit is vegan or not, I'd appreciate the information. Thank you.

P.S.: I am well aware of "accidentally vegan" products labelled as a "vegetarian" as there has been a gradual shift in manufacturers acknowledging and bothering to label products as vegan. I've recently become more careful in my assumptions after I learned that vitamin D3, which I've seen labeled vegetarian, is usually *not vegan* because it may come from sheep's wool.

Comment: `I have not yet attempted to contact Lidl` ... why not? ... please do research before you post here

Comment: As they say, `eat food, not processed food`. Flakes all shapes & forms are processed.

Comment: Fair points. Thought I'd post the question in case somebody already had asked Lidl. And honestly it's unlikely that I would make the time to post a question for which I already knew the answer. I did invest some time researching online though, and posted the links in my question. My intention was to eventually post an answer myself if nobody else did, it just didn't happen yet, sorry! As for the processed food, totally agree, known that for ages, if only I had the discipline... for now I choose to reduce it rather than completely eliminate it. Cereal is an occasional thing for me btw. Thanks!

Comment: For what is worth, I phoned Aldi about the "Harvest Morn Crisp Cereal Strawberry" and the answer was essentially "I don't know". Couldn't open the Lidl customer  service page, it's blank. I can see some JavaScript errors on the developer console...

Comment: I think some of them are yes, but I was quite surprised to see that in Germany customers could win tickets for an aquarium exhibition by buying their cereals.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s an image saying that my favourite muesli, by Crownfield, is vegan.[image]

Comment: Thanks. But their Muesli (at least the one I have seen) has the label `vegan` in the package and says "Suitable for vegetarians and vegans". My question is about the ones that have vegan ingredients but the package only says `vegetarian`.